# Multiplying 2 columns in sql but calculation is incorrect?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT c.compname AS [Company]
    ,e.empname AS [Employee Name]
    ,a.jobid AS [Job Number]
    ,a.JobNavn AS [Job Name]
    ,t.TName [Task Name]
    ,cu.DayDate AS [Booking Date]
    ,cu.HrsBooked AS [Scheduled Hours]
    ,x.Ressnavn AS [Client]
    ,tr.Sale
    ,SUM(cu.HrsBooked) * (tr.Sale) AS [Total]
FROM job a
INNER JOIN jobplan jp ON jp.JobId = a.jobid
INNER JOIN JobDimensions AS z ON z.jobid = a.jobid
INNER JOIN Ress AS x ON x.RessId = z.custid
INNER JOIN JobPrice AS y ON y.JobId = a.Jobid
INNER JOIN task t ON t.PlanId = jp.PlanId
INNER JOIN JobPriceactivity AS w ON w.priceId = y.priceId
INNER JOIN taskres tr ON tr.TaskId = t.TaskId
INNER JOIN emp e ON e.EmpId = tr.ResId
INNER JOIN comp c ON e.compid = c.compid
INNER JOIN CapUsed AS cu ON cu.RefId = tr.TaskResId
    AND cu.RefType = 1
INNER JOIN arpaccount AS ar ON e.empname = ar.arpaccname
    AND CAST(cu.DayDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate
        AND @enddate
WHERE e.EMPID >= '2'
    AND cu.HrsBooked > '0'
GROUP BY c.compname
    ,e.empname
    ,a.jobid
    ,a.JobNavn
    ,t.TName
    ,cu.DayDate
    ,cu.HrsBooked
    ,x.Ressnavn
    ,y.priceid
    ,tr.Sale
```

But the calculation of my 'SUM' in the select is not correct as highlighted in yellow in the following extract

I was expecting something like the below highlighted in green:

[image]

Can anyone highlight where I am going wrong either in my main code or column sum?

Comment: You have no `GROUP BY` and yet you are attempting aggregation.  Something looks wrong.

Comment: @jarlh ha!  thanks for pointing out the obvious... sometimes a second pair of eyes is all that's needed... works now.

Comment: Excellent! (I did just delete that comment, became a bit unsure if it was correct...)

Comment: Why you grouping by `cu.HrsBooked ` and summing it? The `SUM` of a single value will be the single value. Shouldn't it just therefore be `cu.HrsBooked * tr.Sale` and there should be no `GROUP BY`?